# 95% confidence intervals crossing 0 but p < 0.05 in glm gamma family

Tags: confidence-interval, generalized-linear-model, p-value, gamma-distribution

As title suggest:
Is it possible to have confidence intervals crossing 0 but *p* = 0.042?

This happened to me in glm model with gamma family and link identity.
The conf. intervals were generated by tidy function in R.

How should I interpret it? Or is my model wrong?

---

Actualization:

The intervals from tidy functions seems to be based on likelihood ratio. However when I compute the Wald's CI the the values now doesn't cross 0. So is tidy function using different aproache towards CI and *p* value?

Comment: Yes, this sounds like the libraries have different methods of calculating the critical value: Wald vs likelihood ratio.